# How to check if inputted parentheses are valid

Tags: python

Is there an efficient method to find out if a string input uses correctly?

So, "((()))()" is correct.
    "()()(" is incorrect.
    "hi())(" is incorrect.

I have tried this:

```
def valid_parentheses(string): 
    utilList = [] for i in string:     
        utilList.append(i)
    open = utilList.count("(")
    close = utilList.count(")")
    if (open + close) % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: you can recursively\iteratively look for and replace `'()'` with `''` and see if the string you'll end up with is blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python program to check matching of simple parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833819/python-program-to-check-matching-of-simple-parentheses)

Comment: @asongtoruin I tried this: (check the edit)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis how would "(hello)" work?

Comment: @Enesxg There are no letters in OPs example.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through your text and keep count. +1 for `(`, -1 for `)`. At the end of the loop, the counter should be 0. If the counter ever goes negative, you can exit early knowing that they are not balanced.

Comment: "hi())(" would add to 0, but the final use of ")(" is incorrect.

Comment: @Enesxg You'd exit early at the second `)` in that example, because the counter would be -1.

Comment: Thanks,    Bill the Lizard

Comment: Do you have an idea what you would do to check for the " [ ] { } " braces as well?

Comment: @Enesxg I'd do the same thing. Just set up separate counters for each kind of braces.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to track the parentheses nesting level. It starts at 0.

Iterate through the string. Each time you reach an open parenthesis, add 1  the nesting level. Subtract 1 each time you reach a closing parenthesis.

If the number is ever negative, or if the number is not zero when you reach the end of the string, then the parentheses are malformed.

Comment: "hi())(" would add to 0, but the final use of ")(" is incorrect.