# count the bracket [] pairs in string in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string as shown below

```
str1 = 'UPPER([CATEGORY_NAME]+[PRODUCT_NAME])'
```

the string can be any just want to count the no of '[]' pairs in a string

output required:
2

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python program to check matching of simple parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833819/python-program-to-check-matching-of-simple-parentheses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, using regex:

```
import re
len(re.findall(r'\[.+?\]', str1))
```

This will count all bracket pairs that contain at least one character. If you also want to count empty bracket pairs, replace the `+` with a `*` in the regex.

```
len(re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', str1))
```

EDIT:
If you want to get the contents of the brackets, you could do it by using a group inside the regex:

```
content = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', str1)
count = len(contents)
print(content)
>>> ['CATEGORY_NAME', 'PRODUCT_NAME']
```

Comment: What if `str1 = 'UPPER([CATEGORY_NAME]+[[PRODUCT_NAME]])'`? In other words, this doesn't count nested brackets...